# Having some trouble understanding Probability Distributions

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

The question is :
If X has the Distribution Function F(x) = {

0 for x< -1 ,

1/4 for -1 <=x<1 ,

1/2 for 1<= x <3 ,

3/4 for 3<= x < 5 ,

1 for x>=5
}

find

a) P(X<=3)      **= 3/4**

b) P(X=3)       **= 1/4**

c) P(X<3)       **= 1/2**

d) P(X>=1)      **= 3/4**

e) P(-0.4 < X<4) **= 1/2**

f) P(X=5)        ** =1/4**

The answers are from the back of the book. This question directly follows the section on Probability Distribution and Distribution Functions / Cumulative Distribution Functions for Discrete Random Variables if that helps. I got a, b, and f correct. However, I don't understand how they get the answer for c, d, and e. Any help would be appreciated.

my attempts:

a) 1/4 + 1/2 = **3/4**

b) 3/4 - 1/2 = **1/4**

c) 1/2 + 1/4 = 3/4  **wrong**

d) 1/2 **wrong**

e) 3/4 - 0 = 3/4   **wrong**

f) 1 - 3/4  **= 1/4**

Comment: It's a Piecewise function, not a Distribution function (where one would expect the values in the range of the function to sum up to $1$).

Comment: The Question in the book states " If X has the Distribution Function F(x) "

Comment: The cumulative distribution function can be "piecewise" constant if the probability density function is discrete.  The discrete probabilities are values of the "jumps" in the cumulative distribution function (at points of discontinuity).

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), 
[here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), 
[here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and 
[here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote $F_{-}(x)$ for $P(X<x)$.

Then $$F_{-}(x)=\lim_{y\rightarrow x-}F(y)$$ so that e.g. $F_{-}(3)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 3-}F(y)=\frac12$ and $F_{-}(1)=\lim_{y\rightarrow 1-}F(y)=\frac14$.

To give you a start:

a) $F(3)=P(X\leq 3)=\frac34$ .

b) $P(X=3)=F(3)-F_{-}(3)=\frac34-\frac12=\frac14$

c) $P(X<3)=F_{-}(3)=\frac12$

d) $P(X\geq1)=1-P(X<1)=1-F_{-}(1)=1-\frac14=\frac34$

e) $P(-0.4<X<4)=F_{-}(4)-F(-0.4)=\cdots$

et cetera

Answer (score 0):

We have a discrete random variable x with

$P(x=-1)=\frac{1}{4}$, $P(x=1)=\frac{1}{4}$, $P(x=3)=\frac{1}{4}$, and $P(x=5)=\frac{1}{4}$; so

c) $P(x<3)=P(x=-1)+P(x=1)=\frac{1}{2}$.

d) $P(x\ge1)=P(x=1)+P(x=3)+P(x=5)=\frac{3}{4}$.

e) $P(-.4<x<4)=P(x=1)+P(x=3)=\frac{1}{2}$.